# Parse href attribute value from element with Beautifulsoup and Mechanize

Tags: python, django, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Can anyone help me traverse an html tree with beautiful soup?

I'm trying to parse through html output and after gather each value then insert into a table named `Tld` with python/django

```
<div class="rc" data-hveid="53">
<h3 class="r">
<a href="https://billing.anapp.com/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNGqpb38ftdxRdYvKwOsUv5EOJAlpQ','m3fly0i1VLOK9NJkV55hAQ','0CDYQFjAB','','',event)">Billing: Portal Home</a>
</h3>
```

And only parse the value of `href` attribute of `<a>`, so only this part:

```
https://billing.anapp.com/
```

of:

```
<a href="https://billing.anapp.com/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNGqpb38ftdxRdYvKwOsUv5EOJAlpQ','m3fly0i1VLOK9NJkV55hAQ','0CDYQFjAB','','',event)">Billing: Portal Home</a>
```

I currently have:

```
for url in urls:
    mb.open(url)
    beautifulSoupObj = BeautifulSoup(mb.response().read())
    beautifulSoupObj.find_all('h3',attrs={'class': 'r'})
```

The problem is `find_all` above, isn't make it far enough to the `<a>` element.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="rc" data-hveid="53">
<h3 class="r">
<a href="https://billing.anapp.com/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNGqpb38ftdxRdYvKwOsUv5EOJAlpQ','m3fly0i1VLOK9NJkV55hAQ','0CDYQFjAB','','',event)">Billing: Portal Home</a>
</h3>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
elms = bs.select("h3.r a")
for i in elms:
    print(i.attrs["href"])
```

prints:

```
https://billing.anapp.com/
```

`h3.r a` is a [css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

you can use css selector (i prefer them), xpath, or find in elements. the selector `h3.r a` will look for all `h3` with class `r` and get from inside them the `a` elements. it could be a more complicated example like `#an_id table tr.the_tr_class td.the_td_class` it will find an id given td's inside that belong to the tr with the given class and are inside a table of course.

this will also give you the same result. `find_all` returns a list of `bs4.element.Tag`, `find_all` has a recursive field not sure if you can do it in one line, i personaly prefer css selector because its easy and clean.

```
for elm in  bs.find_all('h3',attrs={'class': 'r'}):
    for a_elm in elm.find_all("a"):
        print(a_elm.attrs["href"])
```

Comment: Instead of printing, is it possible to insert into a django table 'tld'?

Comment: @CodeTalk i know nothing about django :(

Comment: thanks for showing me what to do anyway. One question - does BeautifulSoup use more or less CSS-selectors throughout to select elements and sub-element?

Comment: sorry i didnt mention you could also do it with find_all or xpath, but i find css selector the easiest and cleanest way. yes it can get all the sub elements in this case `a`

Comment: i would recommend you the css selectors, when i started parsing i was using regex, then i started using the find methods. when i found that i could do it with css selectors my life became so much easier. it looks a bit scary the first time but its just syntax and about getting used to it

Comment: no worries, i found jsoup a nice way to start with selectors, it has clear explanation on the Description section. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax. have fun !

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning what would happen in case there were similarly named classes that contain spaces.
Taking a piece of code that @Foo Bar User provided and changing it a little

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="rc" data-hveid="53">
<h3 class="r s">
<a href="https://billing.anapp.com/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNGqpb38ftdxRdYvKwOsUv5EOJAlpQ','m3fly0i1VLOK9NJkV55hAQ','0CDYQFjAB','','',event)">Billing: Portal Home</a>
</h3>
<h3 class='r s sth s'>
<a href="https://link_you_dont_want.com/">Don't grab this</a>
</h3>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

when we try to get just the link where class equals 'r s' by css selectors:

```
elms = bs.select("h3.r.s a")
for i in elms:
    print(i.attrs["href"])
```

it prints

```
https://billing.anapp.com/
https://link_you_dont_want.com/
```

however using

```
for elm in  bs.find_all('h3',attrs={'class': 'r s'}):
    for a_elm in elm.find_all("a"):
        print(a_elm.attrs["href"])
```

gives the desired result

```
https://billing.anapp.com/
```

That's just something I've encountered during my own work. If there is a way to overcome this using css selectors, please let me know!